# Connectedness of a set in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this set $$  X=B'((-2,0),1)\cup B'((2,0),1)\cup ([-1,1]\times\{0\})$$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ where $B'$ is the closed ball.

How to prove that $X$ is connected but $\overset{\circ}{X}$ is not connected.

Thank you.

Comment: Does $B'$ just mean the open ball, e.g. $d((x,y),(-2,0))<1$?

Comment: That's connectedness*.

Comment: @coffeemath B' is the closed ball $...\leq 1$

Comment: @Ahmed sorry but what is "connectedness*"?

Comment: Couldn't help but think of Star-wars here.

Comment: @PepperSausage ?????

Comment: The character, R2D2.

Comment: Have you drawn the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are connected sets in metric space $Z$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset $, then $A \cup B$ is connected. Apply this result for $B'((-2,0),1)$ and $[-1,1]\times \{0\}$, then apply to $B'((-2,0),1)\cup [-1,1]\times \{0\}$ and $B'((2,0),1)$. Thus $X = B'((-2,0),1)\cup [-1,1]\times \{0\} \cup B'((2,0),1)$ is connected.

If  $\overset{\circ}{X}$ denotes the interior of the set $X$, then it is easy to see that  interior of $X$ is the disjoint union of two open balls $B((-2,0),1)$ and $B((2,0),1)$, where $B$ denotes the open ball. Thus $\overset{\circ}{X}$ is not connected.

Comment: I suspect the OP's chief difficulty lies in seeing what the interior of $X$ is.  It might be helpful to explain that part a bit more.

Comment: please can you explain me more why $\overset{\circ}{X}=B((-2,0),1)\cup B((2,0),1)$ thank you

Comment: i think that $\overset{\circ}{X}=\overset {\circ}{B'((-2,0),1)} \cup \overset{\circ}{[-1,1]\times\{0\}}\cup \overset{\circ}{B'((2,0),1)}=B((-2,0),1)\cup B((2,0),1)\cup (]-1,1[\times \emptyset)$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou The last part $[-1,1] \times 0$ has an empty interior since working in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: the interior of $[-1,1]\times \{0\}$ is equal to $]-1,1[\times \emptyset$ because the iterior of $\{0\}$ is $\emptyset$ right ?

Comment: The interior of $[-1,1] \times \{0\}$ is the empty set. Because any point in $[-1,1] \times \{0\}$ is of the form $(x,0)$, where $x \in [-1,1]$. So, for any $r>0$, the neighborhood $B((x,0), r)$ contains point $(x, \frac{r}{2})$. Thus the interior of $[-1,1] \times \{0\}$ is empty.

Comment: @mrka is it always true that $\overset{\circ}{\widehat{A\cup B}}=\overset{\circ}{A}\cup\overset{\circ}{B}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou no. For example, take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B= \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\overset{\circ}{\widehat{A\cup B}}= \mathbb{R}$ and $\overset{\circ}{A}\cup\overset{\circ}{B} = \emptyset$.

Comment: @mrka then how is calculated $\overset{\circ}{X}$ ? thank you